# How to compete on a scarce spec'd project to avoid team death-march

Tags: project-management, agile, software-estimation

I'm time+cost estimating a semi-complex software solution, that hasn't got specific requirements in about 75% of features. I would still like to make as good estimate as possible, by getting additional data from the client. There will still be parts that may end up not being able to develop, since there's too many dependencies with other products/technologies and lack of definition. I also have a very tight schedule to produce this estimate.

There will also be other contenders on this project. Client expects a *price+duration* (and probably also features) and I know everyone will be off. I know that's impossible, but tell that to marketing people. Another problem is that I'm talking to middle-man and not directly to the client. **I can get confidence with middle-man only, but not with the deciding client.** Which is a different problem altogether.

What disclaimer/info can I put in my price plan/contract not to *kill* team with this project, so when project starts slipping (in terms of cost/time/features) we will be covered with some sort of payment. I would of course like to be paid by sprints or releases with relation to time, but I doubt client could be convinced in this. I'm sure we can finish this product before deadline and also create a great product, but how can I convice client to believe me?

### Question

**What can I do to get this project and avoid *death march* situation at the same time?**

*Any suggestion welcome!*

### EDIT: Outcome

In the end we (me and my co-worker) convinced the client we need at least a week to evaluate the product. So we did. We also pushed (and got) a slot for a few hours long meeting with the client to clarify any outstanding requirements' questions. So we did. Meeting was done after we made the first estimate draft, so we were sure we have all the questions to point out specifics that were either completely misunderstood or too vague to estimate. I hope we get the project, because it would mean 8 months of full time work for us, plus a reasonable pay. We'll know in about a week and a half.

Of course I also pointed out that the way we'll be delivering this product will get them exactly where they want to be with a product that will actually be what they wanted. And also that we only commit to price and time, but not functionality, because it is and will be subject to change. I think we made a good enough impression.

Comment: Wondering what approach you ended up taking with this and would like to hear the outcome as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to the world of fixed priced development services :-)

Techniques for to win this project and avoid death march situation at the same time:

- Don't underbid a project.  Bid for what you think the project will take and add some percentage for things likely to go wrong.
- If you are missing 75% of the detail, odds are the project will be significantly different than you currently expect.  Document some reasonable detail assumptions within the outline of the defined work.  When the project actually starts and the details don't match the assumption, you have an opportunity to negotiate the costs for the changes.  At that time, you may also be in a better position to know how much you are over/under and attempt to compensate with this quote.
- Your goal in an SOW (statement of work) should be to define enough details so that it gives you an opportunity to renegotiate the cost of changes when you know more about the project. Write these as positives, as much as possible.  Note, it is unlikely that people that actually understand the project will read or understand the SOW...I base this on the point that you are given few details to quote.  This means it isn't a consultative sale and neither party is really focused on building the 'right' solution.
- If you can get a contract as T&M (time and materials) great.  I doubt you'll get it or unable to get it without some restrictions that essentially defeat the purpose of a T&M.  Your potential customers look at this as them accepting all of the risks around your abilities.
- Hopefully, you aren't the first at your company to do this.  Find out, historically, how projects have been and the typical result rates.  Many software development groups charge an hourly rate that is significantly higher than cost...but their quotes tend to be lower and not actual hours.  Customers often will argue more about the hours/days than the actual quote.  Enterprises tend to be used to paying high hourly rates.
- Figure out your department's expected margin (profit you need to gain from the job).  This may help you to understand how much of a 'death march' you may face when your project slips.
- In the SOW specify the level of detail that will be required in a specification before you begin work.  While Agile and other customer focused processes take an approach that oriented at finding the best solution, they aren't designed to keep costs under control in a fixed bid environment.  You will need to take a waterfall approach to requirements and then build in an agile fashion so that you can adjust along the way.  The specification, like the SOW, will give you an opportunity to bill for changes.  While the customer won't like this, it will put the burden and risks associated with requirements on them and not your team.

Note, to be successful with these negotiations, you needs a supportive management, sales and project management team.  If you don't have that, you are bound to always be on 'death marches.'  Even if you forgo quality, process, testing and other items, you'll find there's never enough time for a project.

Answer (score 13):

In this economic environment, there are a lot of companies competing for a little work. Someone is bound to give them a very sweet bid that will

1. Not be able to deliver on,
2. Kill their team with, or
3. Both.

When they can't deliver at the agreed price, they will start to cut down on the quality in order to deliver something and get paid.

Your challenge is to present that fact to your prospect in a professional manner, and convince them that you will work very hard to deliver at a reasonable cost, but also to deliver exactly what they need.  The fact that you're going back for more detail, and the method you approach the project with (agile... but be sure and explain the business benefit to them) helps ensure that they will end up with what they really need.

Remember, they want to get the software delivered **that they need** at the lowest possible price.

Convince them that you will deliver exactly to their needs, and that your price is reasonable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on: "present that fact to your prospect in a professional manner". I can tell them in my words, but would that be professional? Do you have any special approach?

Comment: Don't make it sound like a case of sour grapes that other companies may bid less.  Instead, focus on your strengths and why you will deliver what they need.  Don't emphasize the fact that other companies will not deliver what they need.  Either make it subtle or just let them reach that conclusion.  If you say something like "the reason why I'm asking you for this additional detail is because I want to ensure we deliver exactly what you need, in high quality, with the budget we agree to" a reasonable person should ask themselves how other companies can bid realistically without that detail.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**:

Addressing the middle-men situation.  I think the best course of action would be to submit a list of *risks* along with your bid as a courtesy to the customer.  Kind of like giving them a heads-up on what their project limitations are.  This will cost you some work up front but I think it could help you win the project.

---

you have two options

**make a best-guess** and double or triple your estimate (your competition is probably doing the same thing.)

**explain** to the customer that you can't bid work like this, and tell him that everyone else that gives him a fixed estimate is probably not being completely truthful.

At the end of the day, if you can't make money on the work, the there is not point in trying for it.

Personally, I prefer the latter, up-front and honest communication with your customers will take you farther than any bid tricks ever will.

Comment: There's also middle men between me and the client. That's why there are even more variables... Knowing the market at least a bit I think they won't buy the argument of "tell him that everyone else that gives him a fixed estimate is probably not being completely truthful". And I'm afraid if I triple my estimate I probably won't get the project.

Comment: ah, good point.  I didn't know that.  See my edits.

Comment: I'll try to set-up at least two meetings fr them to get to know my methods. They may find value in them.

Comment: yeah, see what you can do.  The more they understand that bidding software is not a cut-and-dry process the better off you are.  You also might want to bid for individual milestones, like once you complete one, you get to bid the second, etc...

Comment: I don't think this kind of bidding is possible since other competitors would be in a much harder position since they would upgrade an existing codebase not done by them. Milestones make sense for the client to actually have a grasp of business value of certain functionality and easier cutoff certain parts that pose too much effort with lower business value.

Comment: exactly, which is good for you if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

A few things I'd say you should think about:

**Assumptions:**  There's no one disclaimer you can add but you need to fill the gaps in the requirements with sensible assumptions and document them.  Nothing major or scary, just a section in your spec/bid with a list of bullet points saying what you assumed to be true which was missing (e.g. users details will be pulled using LDAP and no admin screens will be written to cover user admin).

This gives you clarity in estimating as you now have a full scope to work from, but it also means that if the client comes back with things which are wildly different you have a fair basis to start talking about raising change requests and varying the cost.  Alternatively they may come back during the negotiations saying this assumption or that one isn't true and you have more information.

**Out of Scope:**  A specific case of assumptions - list things which you aren't including (e.g.  No integration will exist with system X).  Again this allows you to have a full scope and a reasonable case for potentially varying cost at a later stage.

Assumptions and out of scope are particularly applicable when things are mentioned in passing but not really followed up, or for things which they say could wait for a second phase.  These are often the things the client will believe are being done as part of the main project but the project team don't.

Hopefully the thoroughness and insight from the assumptions and scope you define will help inspire confidence with the ultimate client too.

**Contingency:**  A tricky one but you should add contingency in two ways:

(1) for specific risks.  For things which might mean something takes longer than you've estimated then put in an amount to cover that weighted by the chance of it happening.  Add all these up and that's your risk contingency.

(2) Shit happens contingency - unpredictable shit happens on IT projects.  Add between 10% and 20% to cover this.

Whether you hide contingency from your commercial people and the client or not depends on your relationship but if it gets removed they need to understand what that means (essentially you WILL over run).

**Understand the relationship between effort and cost:**  As a technologist your role is to provide an estimate of the effort based on the information you have.  You need to then communicate that with assumptions, level of contingency and so on to your commercial team who can convert it into a monetary value.  The thing to be clear with them on is that if they want to drop the cost that doesn't change the effort.

There are loads of good reasons for writing down the cost to the client (to build a relationship, because you'll end up with stuff you can reuse later and so on) but people need to understand that unless the scope changes the effort stays the same - the reduction comes out of the profit.

Comment: These are really nice suggestions. I'll try to write these down.

Answer (score 1):

i have a blog article which may have a few tips in it for you:

http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2009/06/surviving-under-resourced-project.html

one of the other posters here has a good point to. there will always be someone who will offer a lower price to get the work. and the developer will suffer for it later (i.e. having to do a lot of free work to satisfy the client).

some clients need to have this experience before it clicks that you cant do IT projects on the cheap without paying some kind of price.

LM

Comment: Both clients are big: the middle man is a multinational marketing agency that will compete for the project with the end multinational IT client. But it all depends on experience of people involved. - But your blog post has valuable information +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Go for realism. Avoid promising too much, then make a point of it.

A lot of customers out there have been burnt by unrealistic offerers who fail to deliver as promised.

Emphasize the need for a specifications sprint. Convey a focus on core functionality and commitment to deliver rather than a feature bonanza. Offer a primary development phase to deliver core functionality.

Communicate the power and safety of the agile approach. Credit the customer with the ability to see good sense.

In short: Strive to come across as realistic and serious (more so than your competitors). The most important thing for any serious customer in the end is **not** the price, but a confidence that the product will be delivered on time and budget.

Comment: Well direct client communication is not done directly by me... I can only deliver as much info to middle-man as possible.